# $($string) execution failure

Tags: bash, variable

I have `$(${StrVar})`, my `StrVar` has `$` in value eg. `test$9hp`.

When I execute the command: `$(${StrVar}` it fails as `$9` is inside my variable and it tries to expand it.

```
function Deploy
{
  # in this function 
  output=$(echo ${1})
  echo "$output" 
}

Deploy "test$9hp"
```

How to avoid execution of string value which includes `$9`?

Comment: Which shell are you using?  Also please provide a real test scenario demonstrating the problem; as you've written it this works in `bash` as expected; `$ x='test$9hp' ; $(${x})
bash: test$9hp: command not found`

Comment: am using bash shell. real scenario is this x='test$9hp' am passing this value to some function so it becomes $(echo ${1}). when command executes it execute $9 in value and prints output as testhp: command not found. i don't want $9 to execute

Comment: Please update the question with relevant minimal example; that'll get the formatting correct and we can see _exactly_ what you are doing;  "some function" isn't sufficiently clear.

Comment: function main {
Deploy "test$9hp"
}

function Deploy {
# in this function 
output=$(echo ${1})
echo "$output"

}

Comment: The problem is your `Deploy "test$9hp"` should be `Deploy 'test$9hp'` ; the `$9` is being evaluated at that point.

Comment: if I try it individually suggested by you. it works fine. but i have one more case outputDataDft=$(ant -f ${mydir}/Build.xml -Dparam='test$9hp'). in this case when I print param, I get testhp.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Deploy "test\$9gh"` and with the `set -x`, your script show:

   `+ Deploy 'test$9hp'
   ++ echo 'test$9hp'
   + output='test$9hp'
   + echo 'test$9hp'
   test$9hp
   + set +x`

It not expand it.